# Facebook Graph API - Field attachments specified more than once. This is only possible before version 2.1

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using the FB Graph API explorer and version 11.0 I've added the page id, feed and fields. Previously we were using 'link' and 'title' but according to the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.3/) those are deprecated and these are the new field names:

```
attachments{unshimmed_url}
attachments{title}
```

but when I add this to the FB Graph API Explorer I either get the error:

> Field attachments specified more than once. This is only possible
> before version 2.1

or I only get the first mentioned attachments field (attachments{unshimmed_url})

```
1234567/feed?fields=attachments{unshimmed_url}&attachments{title}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Can’t reproduce this error right now, using v11.0, but</del> it should work if you just list the sub-fields comma separated:

```
…/feed?fields=attachments{unshimmed_url,title}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion

---

Edit: *Can* reproduce, with the “correct” incorrect syntax.
`feed?fields=attachments{unshimmed_url},attachments{title}` throws this error; you had `feed?fields=attachments{unshimmed_url}&attachments{title}` in your post, which is a different thing - that’s one URL parameter named `fields`, and then one named `attachments{title}`